# cURL in Postman

Tags: curl, postman

I am trying to import a cURL command into POSTMAN.

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY" https://api.astria.ai/tunes \
          -F tune[callback]="http://localhost/" \
          -F tune[title]="my portrait" \
          -F tune[branch]="fast" \
          -F tune[name]=person \
          -F "tune[images][]=@1.jpg" \
          -F "tune[images][]=@2.jpg" \
          -F "tune[images][]=@3.jpg" \
          -F "tune[images][]=@4.jpg"

{
  "id": 1,
  "images": [
    "http://assets.astria.ai/1.jpg",
    "http://assets.astria.ai/2.jpg",
    "http://assets.astria.ai/3.jpg",
    "http://assets.astria.ai/4.jpg"
  ],
  "name": "person",
  "steps": null,
  "ckpt_url": null,
  "created_at": "2022-10-06T14:06:09.088Z",
  "updated_at": "2022-10-06T14:06:09.139Z",
  "url": "http://api.astria.ai/tunes/26.json"
}
```

But I am getting this error:

> Error while importing Curl: Only the URL can be provided without an
> option preceding it.All other inputs must be specified via options.

How can I fix it? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported it into postman as a single line.

This imported:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY" https://api.astria.ai/tunes -F tune[callback]="http://localhost/" -F tune[title]="my portrait" -F tune[branch]="fast" -F tune[name]=person -F "tune[images][]=@1.jpg" -F "tune[images][]=@2.jpg" -F "tune[images][]=@3.jpg" -F "tune[images][]=@4.jpg"
```

But postman is looking for the file names `Select Files`.

[image: Postman]

But if I removed the @, the file names imported.

[image]

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $API_KEY" https://api.astria.ai/tunes -F tune[callback]="http://localhost/" -F tune[title]="my portrait" -F tune[branch]="fast" -F tune[name]=person -F "tune[images][]=1.jpg" -F "tune[images][]=2.jpg" -F "tune[images][]=3.jpg" -F "tune[images][]=4.jpg"
```